# can identify and authenticate an ldap user in one of two distinct, separate domains?

Tags: linux, ldap

Most people configure PAM and NSS ldap modules to point to ldap servers that handles a single search base as defined in pam_ldap.conf or libnss-ldap.conf. The man pages do not describe any option to specify multiple bases.

Is it possible to configure a Linux system to use more than one base that are handled by different ldap servers, so that if a user is not found in the first domain, the system searches for the user in the next one, and keeps trying each different base until it finds the user or until it has exhausted all of them?

The case scenario that I'm working on is that I have a local LDAP server I set up serving `base dc=yyyy` and I've got a separate ldap directory I set up in jumpcloud with `base ou=Users,o=<orgid>,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com`. This directory has  different set of users from the first. When a user logs in, I'd like the system to search first the local ldap directory; if it doesn't find the user there I'd like it to authenticate against the jumpcloud directory.

Comment: Did you find resolution to this problem? I need to implement something similar.

Comment: @haba713 Nope, unfortunately I never got a resolution for it. And this was just a short-term contract project for me a few years ago, so when it ended, I didn't bother pursuing the answer any more.